# Is StackOverflow for professional programmers or for newbiew too?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, asking-questions

As stated in: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
>   who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
>   questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question
>   generally covers…

I stared answering question of a user. Which in the end did not even understand what he wanted: [PHP. Check if a couple [Key]=>[Value] already exists in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600385/php-check-if-a-couple-key-value-already-exists-in-an-array/27600529?noredirect=1#27601204)

I flagged this answer. But no reaction was taken.

In what I understand, Stackoverflow is place, where people with basic knowledge about programming ask question.

And this question is about something, that person asking the question does not even understand and have no basic knowledge about even loops.

So, is should questions like this exist or not? **As it will lead nowhere and would turn out into  tutorial on "how to program"** if anyone ever tried to answer this to make asking person happy about answer (if its ever possible)

Comment: The conclusion from the linked post top answer by Robert is clear: No.

Comment: No? "No, its not good question" or "No, you're wrong"? So this question is considered "proper and answered"?

Comment: I mean "No, such questions should not exist" in response to your "should questions like this exist or not?".

Comment: Oh, thank you. "No" is such tricky answer :)

Comment: When out of context of course, but I was hoping the answer I linked to gave enough context. :)